# Android OnCreate procedure executes when device rotate?

Tags: android

My question is very simple.

When an activity run the onCreate() function executes. However when I rotate the iPhone it seems the OnCreate runs again.

I access a remote database to get rows of data. Is there a On????() function that get called only ONCE per activity or Do I need to check if the device rotates to prevent from re-reading the database.

I want to be able to rotate but only access the db once if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity restart on rotation Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: Do you have `Android` OS on your `iPhone`?...Change the approach. E.g. use a singleton for the remote calls. Read [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `onCreate()` will be executed after each device rotation, if did not configured `android:configChanges` Activity attribute properly in your AndroidManifest.xml

Usually it's OK to reread data in this case.

But if you cares about traffic, you should cache locally the data you have read from remote server. Use `SQLite` database to store the data and timestamp when you got it.